# Ruby on rails installation dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running cloned ruby project first time.
Issue is while running command bundle update terminal throws following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.4)

    bootstrap-tooltip-rails (~> 0.1) was resolved to 0.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.1)

    client_side_validations was resolved to 17.0.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 5.0.0.1, < 6.1)
```

I know it is related to compatibility,but how to solve this? Also i want to install everything in gem file with command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to install

```
rails - 4.0.4
client_side_validations - 17.0.0
```

[`client_side_validations - 17.0.0`](https://rubygems.org/gems/client_side_validations/versions/17.0.0)  depends on `rails` version `>= 5.0.0.1, < 6.1`, which doesn't matches your rails version dependency.

The latest version of `client_side_validations` which supports `rails 4.0.4` is [`client_side_validations - 4.2.12`](https://rubygems.org/gems/client_side_validations/versions/4.2.12)

Update the below version in your Gemfile and install:

***Gemfile***

```
gem 'client_side_validations', '4.2.12'
```